# How to Edit Web Projects

Tags: laravel, web, web-deployment

I've finished my first laravel website project. Before launching it, I'd like to know how to modify my project when I want to update it like changing styles, editing texts?

Comment: There is a thing called git, it does that, and you can update your project by pulling the changes with it

Comment: Ok, so if I edit my web project on Github, will this effect on the actual website?

Comment: Well once you commit your changes and push/pull them yes, you will need to look at the documentation, you can start here for exemple : https://git-scm.com/video/what-is-version-control